# Why can I use UserManager & SignInManager in a Blazor server app

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I am successfully using UserManager & SignInManager in a Blazor server page:

```
[Inject]
private SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager { get; set; } = default!;

[Inject]
private UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; set; } = default!;
```

I'm calling them to create a new user in the Identity DB and they work fine. And then yesterday [I read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

> ASP.NET Core abstractions, such as SignInManager and
> UserManager, aren't supported in Razor components. For more
> information on using ASP.NET Core Identity with Blazor, see Scaffold
> ASP.NET Core Identity into a Blazor Server app.

So what's going on here? Is using these something that will fail on me at times? Or is this warning about something else?

Comment: Disclaimer-- totally not an expert in this area.  However AFAIK, a browser won't let you alter things like Identity claims after the circuit is establish (i.e. after the initial HTTP request).  I suspect you may have problems if you attempt navigation.  Someone more knowledgeable can let me know if I have it wrong.